# Receive answer back behind a firewall

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firewall, iot

I'm currently working on an IoT product.
My question is how can i initiate a connection to the outside and listen for an answer without port forwarding ?

When in the same network (@home) I'm using a simple udp socket on a known port.

Is there a protocol/solution?

What i did for the moment is to use Firebase Cloud Messaging to reach the outside, but of course a smartphone can't answer back to the IoT (Json request at the moment).

```
IoT --> Cloud --> App
```

but not

```
Iot <-- Cloud <-- App
```

Can I solve this by using XMPP requests in FCM?

You have to imagine a daily scenario for an end customer product.

Comment: Without port forwarding, you would need a Cloud server to mediate the connection. _Somebody_ needs to be listening, and the App cannot do it.

Comment: I was thinking to a MQTT server with broker/clients on top of the firebase notification system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Firebase features will work solely with outgoing HTTPS connections, without requiring that you open an incoming port on the device.

One example of this is the Firebase Database, which comes with an Android SDK that purely relies on a (web) socket connection *from* the device *to* the Firebase servers. The REST API to the Firebase Database works in the same infrastructure, except it uses regular HTTP requests instead of web sockets. But both Web Sockets and HTTP requests go over the regular HTTPS port (443). So unless your Firewall blocks HTTP(S) traffic, this approach should work.

In a scenario like this, you'd use the Firebase Database as the intermediary between the Android app and the IoT devices.

Comment: I'm not sure about your answer, what i meant is that even HTTP is actually  firewalled for incoming traffic. Port 80 or 443 must be open somewhere, either in the IoT or in the phone app.